# How to write "key is not pressed"

Tags: javascript

I have line of code that turns a boolean statement from "false" to "true" if it receives an input from the WASD keys and the shift key at the same time. What I want to do is then turn that statement to "false" when there is no input from the WASD keys and the shift key.

Here's what I currently have (the code is in JavaScript):

```
var inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var inputY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if(inputX  != 0.0 || inputY != 0.0 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        IsMoving = true;       
    }

    else if(inputX == 0.0 && inputY == 0.0)
    {
        IsMoving = false;      
    }
```

Is there a way to write something like "ReleaseKey"? Because with what I currently have, after pressing one of the WASD keys and the shift button at the same time, the statement gets stuck in "true".

Comment: `getkeyup` for when they're released?

Comment: I already tried getkeyup before asking the question and it would cause the boolean statement to be stuck on "true" until I pressed shift again, in other words, I would start sprinting, let go of W and Shift and the IsMoving statement would still be true, until I pressed shift again